# Display text JSP from an another page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm trying to display a Comment section under a photo.

Let me introduce the code that I'm using

```
<%
        
    try {
        int id_user;
        int id_imag;
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mydb","root","root"); 
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Feed");
      while(rs.next()){
          
          id_user = rs.getInt("id_user");
          id_imag = rs.getInt("id_image"); 
          //out.println(id_imag);
    %>
         
          <img src="getImageFeed.jsp?id_imag=<%=id_imag%>" width="400px"/><br/>
                        <!-- comment <img src="getComment.jsp?id_imag=<%=id_imag%>" width="400px">-->

          <%
                      
             try{
                 Connection con1 =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mydb","root","root"); 

              PreparedStatement ps = con1.prepareStatement("select * from Comment where id_image = ?");
              ps.setInt(1, id_imag);
              ResultSet rs1 = ps.executeQuery();

ps.setInt(1, id_imag);

while(rs1.next()){
    int id_userC = rs1.getInt("id_user");
    String text = rs1.getString("text");
    out.println(id_userC);
    out.print(text);
    %><br/><%
}
```

Basicly i'm trying to put that code in Another JSP page to call that method. Firstvall I tried to put as like an Image but it didn't work.

At the end I want to be like :

<smth src="getComment?id_imag=<%=id_imag%>"

If you have any idea tell me, thanks. I did my research but I encounter only with request.getParameter but I think it can be possible to get the data from an another page without that method

Comment: Here you don't need to create con1 instance, you can reuse variable con. I mean don't call DriverManager.getConnection() for same arguments to reduce extra time

Comment: Okay, I can erease some line of codes then. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

For now the method to do another While to have the comment is working but it is not pretty and I'm sure that I can display comments from an another page...
Like the image I'm displaying from the getImage

Edit : My answer is not final, It's just a way to finding the missing piece.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If the method works, you can share the code to help other person that will have same issue ?

Comment: I guess you didnt understand my problem... I want this method of retrieving thoses comments under a photo to be on another JSP page. It works to have the method on the page itself but I want it to work on another JSP page. That the code under rs1.next() can work on another JSP page. And on this page to call this method and return me all the comment of this Image. I hope I make sens